# Removing Text and Italic formatting from Wikipedia XML text?

Tags: java, xml, regex, string, xml-parsing

This link - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Wiki_markup#Text_formatting%20first%20point - states that whenever one bolds or italicize the text it is enclosed in either 2 apostrophes for''italicize text'' in 3 apostrophes for '''bold the text''' and 5 apostrophes '''''bold italics''''', I want to be able to take in a String which has this type of formatting as input as an input into the function and remove this sort of markup from the string to return clean text, what kind of regex should I write in java to achieve this, I am new to regexes and have no clue about doing this. Sample Content -

Input

ranked him #'''89''' of the top 500 singles wrestlers

Output

ranked him #89 of the top 500 singles wrestlers

Comment: String.replaceAll("'","");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, [replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
    String sample = "ranked him #'''89''' of the top 500 singles wrestlers";
    System.out.println(""+sample.replaceAll("'", ""));
```

output :

```
ranked him #89 of the top 500 singles wrestlers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly replace groups of 2-3 apostrophes with the following regex:

`[']{2,3}`

Search for that pattern and replace with nothing.  This should work since you're not trying to extract matches.

Comment: and if there are 5 apostrophes how do I do that, and most importantly how do I remove them from the string under consideration.

Comment: Try the replaceAll method.  In the above pattern, [']{2,3} means between 2 and 3.  You could change those numbers to any range you like, or, if you want, you could run a second replace with [']{5}.